# Rendering PDF application in C# application

Tags: c#, pdf

Hey guys, before you guys say anything I have searched and can not find specific information on what I am looking for.

I am looking to display a PDF in my winform application without dependancy. I know of a [library](http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewernet/) (open source) that does this however, it is old. What I mean is that I want the render to be using the latest (or somewhat newer) specification for PDF. Two things I am mainly looking for is bookmarks (which this library supports) and clickable links (like the table of contents) which this library does not support.

I am not a very advanced programmer so if you give me Ghostwriter + PDFsharp or itextpdf or something like that, i can not put together what I need and in time also. So I am looking for links to libraries (open source please) that do this for me.

My alternative is to just use a webbrowser control and set the URL to the pdf but I am looking for something without this dependancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out reporting systems, like Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services, or Crystal Reports, or any of the many reporting solutions (like [Devexpress XtraReports](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/), [ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/), SyncFUsion [Essential Reporting](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition) and quite a few more) for .NET out there? Most of those have some more or less advanced PDF rendering capabilities.

Several vendors also have separate, stand-alone PDF generators, something like [Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/pdf) by Syncfusion or [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) - but those get quite involved if you want to get good results. But it might be worth a look at least...

Yet another approach

Answer (score 1):

One perhaps not so great option is to convert it to an XPS document which is very easy to display in WPF.

Comment: Not necessaraily. The original files are in word format. I am just saving them as PDF with preserves the table of contents and such. So maybe I can save them as XPS, however I do not want it to be edit-able.

Comment: PDF is as editable as XPS, I think. Given Word files, I'm pretty sure you can use the XPS printer driver to print to a XPS file.